# Регулярное выражение для телефонных номеров

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Телефон 111-111-1 попадает под раздачу, хотя он мне не нужен. Странно, т.к. символ `\b`свидетельствует именно о конце строки такого типа. Можете помочь?

```
let str = "Phone numbers: 11-11-11 && 111-111-1, 111-11-11.. 111-111";
// let regex = /\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}\b/g;
// let regex = /\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}\b/g;
// let regex = /\d{3}-\d{3}\b/g;

let regex = /[^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}\b | \d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}\b | \d{3}-\d{3}\b]/g;

str = str.replace(regex, "");
console.log(str);
```

Comment: а чот вы таким образом получить хотите - https://regex101.com/r/71LWFc/1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`111-111-1` у Вас подходило под условие `\d{3}-\d{3}`.

Вы можете сделать [так](https://regex101.com/r/71LWFc/2), чтобы исключить знак `-` из этой группы.

```js
let str = "Phone numbers: 11-11-11 && 111-111-1, 111-11-11.. 111-111";

let regex = /(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2})|(\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2})|(\d{3}-\d{3}(?!-))/g;

console.log(str.match(regex));
str = str.replace(regex, "");
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Благодарствую!!!